# I want to parallelize this function with openMP, but I have a 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'. what is wrong?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp

This is a function from LAME encoder, when I parallelize with `#pragma` omp for ther result is a **core dumped**; how I should to parallelize this function?

I think that the pointer is the problem with OpenMP, the threads increment  wrong memory address.

```
static void quantize_lines_xrpow(unsigned int l, FLOAT istep, const FLOAT * xp, int *pi)
{
  fi_union *fi;
  unsigned int remaining;
  int i;
  assert(l > 0);

  fi = (fi_union *) pi;

  l = l >> 1;
  remaining = l % 2;
  l = l >> 1;
  double x0,x1,x2,x3;
  #pragma omp parallel for private(i)

  for(i=l;i>0;i--){//while (l--) {
      x0 = istep * xp[0];
      x1 = istep * xp[1];
      x2 = istep * xp[2];
      x3 = istep * xp[3];

    x0 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[0].f = x0;
    x1 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[1].f = x1;
    x2 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[2].f = x2;
    x3 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[3].f = x3;

    fi[0].f = x0 + adj43asm[fi[0].i - MAGIC_INT];
    fi[1].f = x1 + adj43asm[fi[1].i - MAGIC_INT];
    fi[2].f = x2 + adj43asm[fi[2].i - MAGIC_INT];
    fi[3].f = x3 + adj43asm[fi[3].i - MAGIC_INT];

    fi[0].i -= MAGIC_INT;
    fi[1].i -= MAGIC_INT;
    fi[2].i -= MAGIC_INT;
    fi[3].i -= MAGIC_INT;
    fi += 4;
    xp += 4;
};
if (remaining) {
    double  x0 = istep * xp[0];
    double  x1 = istep * xp[1];

    x0 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[0].f = x0;
    x1 += MAGIC_FLOAT;
    fi[1].f = x1;

    fi[0].f = x0 + adj43asm[fi[0].i - MAGIC_INT];
    fi[1].f = x1 + adj43asm[fi[1].i - MAGIC_INT];

    fi[0].i -= MAGIC_INT;
    fi[1].i -= MAGIC_INT;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many shared variables among threads, `x0, x1, x2, x3, fi, xp` which result in lot of data races. This includes the pointers (arrays) `fi` and `xp`. The threads increment these nondeterministically thus any dereference of that is error.

Comment: I need control to acces to fi.f and fi.i the problem is in this variables